# Modified a-star pathfinding heuristic design

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

FIRST,
The ideal path was (in order of importance):

```
1. shortest
```

My heuristic (f) was:

```
manhattan distance (h) + path length (g)
```

This was buggy because it favored paths which veered towards the target then snaked back.

SECOND,
The ideal path was:

```
1. shortest
2. approaches the destination from the same y coordinate (if of equal length)
```

My heuristic stayed the same. I checked for the second criteria at the end, after reaching the target. The heuristic was made slightly inefficient (to fix the veering problem) which also resulted in the necessary adjacent coordinates always being searched.

THIRD,
The ideal path:

```
1. shortest
2. approaches the destination from the same y coordinate (if of equal length)
3. takes the least number of turns
```

Now I tried making the heuristic (f):

```
manhattan distance (h) + path length (g) * number of turns (t)
```

This of course works for criteria #1 and #3, and fixes the veering problem inherently. Unfortunately it's now so efficient that testing for criteria #2 at the end is not working because the set of nodes explored is not large enough to reconstruct the optimal solution.

Can anyone advise me how to fit criteria #2 into my heuristic (f), or how else to tackle this problem?

CRITERIA 2 example: If the goal is (4,6) and the paths to (3,6) and (4,5) are of identical length, then the ideal solution should go through (3,6) because it approaches from the Y plane instead, of (4,5) which comes from the X plane. However if the length is not identical, then the shortest path must be favored regardless of what plane it approaches in.

Comment: To clarify: the heuristic I'm talking about is the one used to sort the nodes, to decide which is checked first. I don't know much about the technicals of a-star, this is a custom implementation.

Comment: By "number of turns", do you mean the number of turns made so far in the partial path, or an estimate of the number of turns yet to take?

Comment: number of turns = turns taken in the partial path

Comment: The problem is that my algorithm has so many special cases etc that it's actually a really convoluted version of a-star which tries to be efficient and when I have to add something new some of the special cases are broken.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing the A* heuristic, what [Russell & Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) call *h*, with the partial path cost *g*. Together, these constitute the priority *f* = *g* + *h*.

The heuristic should be an optimistic estimate of how much it costs to reach the goal from the current point. Manhattan distance is appropriate for *h* if steps go up, down, left and right and take at least unit cost.

Your criterion 2, however, should go in the path cost *g*, not in *h*. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "approaches the destination from the same y coordinate", but you can forbid/penalize entry into the goal node by giving all other approaches an infinite or very high path cost. There's strictly no need to modify the heuristic *h*.

The number of turns taken so far should also go in the partial path cost *g*. You may want to include in *h* an (optimistic) estimate of how many turns there are left to take, if you can compute such a figure cheaply.

Comment: I really don't think the letters I use should be so important. I have been using using f directly as the "heuristic" which is used to sort the nodes. I could modify g or h instead but the result is the same because f is composed of the two.

Comment: They are important because they signify completely different variables, both of which have to meet constraints for the A* algorithm to be correct. If you start mixing path cost and heuristic, it becomes very hard to reason or communicate about your algorithm's guarantees and performance.

Comment: The problem is that I have 3-4 actual "heuristics"/measures of a given node which are favored in absolute order of preference when reducing the path. The beauty of the (f) heuristic seems to be that it must be designed to explore all the necessary nodes, although it itself it will not give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question with somewhat of a HACK. Still interested in other answers, ideas, comments, if you know of a better way to solve this.

Hacked manhattan distance is calculated towards the nearest square in the Y plane, instead of the destination itself:

```
dy = min(absolute_value(dy), absolute_value(dy-1));
```

Then when constructing heuristic (f):

```
h = hacked_manhattan_distance();
if (h < 2)
   // we are beside close to the goal
   // switch back to real distance
    h = real_manhattan_distance();
```